# Windows Makefiles and TEXINPUTS

Tags: windows, makefile, tex

*Remark: Put this Question on tex.stackexchange and was adviced to also ask here*

Under Windows (using make from GnuWin32) i want to set my TEXINPUTS variable in a makefile

My Structure is as follows:

```
./
|-texmf_project/
   |-Package.sty
|-main.tex
|-makefile
```

I want to be able to use Package.sty in my compilation process. The files look like this:
Package.sty contains:

```
\ProvidesClass{Package}[]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
```

main.tex contains:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{Package}
\begin{document}
    Hello World\\
    \red{Hello World}
\end{document}
```

Now i want to set the TEXINPUTS to include what is in ./texmf-project/
Hence my Makefile:

```
edit:
    set TEXINPUTS=./texmf-project//;
    pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode main.tex
    del *.log
    del *.aux
```

However this does not seem to make the location available for compilation.
However if I put the line
 `set TEXINPUTS=./texmf-project//;` directly into the cmd and run make afterwards it works.

I believe I am making a mistake with the set, but I am far from beeing an expert.
Any helps or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Fixed a spelling mistake

Comment: Don't you want `:` so you won't overwrite the previous content?

Comment: I have now read so many things on this, I cant remember,wether to use ; or : on windows. However, it doesnt effect my current problem, so i will tackle it afterwards. Thanks for reading my question

Answer (score 1):

Please remember that every recipe line is executed in a separate shell, so your `set` is executed in a different shell than `pdflatex`. Either put those two commands on a single line, or concatenate lines with `\` so that lines are executed in a single shell, i.e.:

```
edit:
    set TEXINPUTS=./texmf-project//; \
    pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode main.tex
```

Edit:

Since this is Windows, it gets more complicated. Just adding `\` and even `&` is not enough, since `make` will run it in a single line (through a batch file):

```
> type Makefile
all:
    set TEXINPUTS=./texmf-project// & \
    echo %TEXINPUTS%

> make -dr
...
Must remake target 'all'.
Creating temporary batch file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\make11444-1.bat
Batch file contents:
        @echo off
        set TEXINPUTS=./texmf-project// & echo %TEXINPUTS%
...
ECHO is off.
...
```

Now, `cmd.exe` uses a line parser that expands variables when the line is parsed, so it first expands `%TEXINPUTS%` to an empty string (since it was not yet defined) and after that it evaluates the code which sets the variable. Therefore it is crucial that those commands are on separate lines to have variable set before it is used. The easiest way (if you use quite modern make) is including a `.ONESHELL` directive which would place all recipe into the batch and execute all at once:

```
> type Makefile
.ONESHELL:

all:
    set TEXINPUTS=./texmf-project//
    echo %TEXINPUTS%

> make -dr
...
Must remake target 'all'.
Creating temporary batch file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\make29908-1.bat
Batch file contents:
        @echo off
        set TEXINPUTS=./texmf-project//
        echo %TEXINPUTS%
...
./texmf-project//
...
```

Alternatively, if you don't somehow calculate the value, you can just set the variable at the `make` level (global or target level) and export it to the process, i.e.:

```
> type Makefile
all: export TEXINPUTS := ./texmf-project//
all:
    echo %TEXINPUTS%

> make -dr
...
Must remake target 'all'.
Creating temporary batch file C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\make25392-1.bat
Batch file contents:
        @echo off
        echo %TEXINPUTS%
...
./texmf-project//
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I was not aware of that. However, when I do this, the pdflatex command is no longer run. I think maybe it is just appended to the TEXINPUTS variable.

Comment: Adding an & between commands solves this. But it still does not set TEXINPUTS properly

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Sadly, it still doesnt work for me. I used both your examples and make only ever produced %TEXINPUTS% as an output from echo, as if it treats it like a string or something. I think, I will just adapt my workflow and try using the wsl. I can not get familiar with cmd it seems.